# Docker setup for Wirecloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to set up a local version of Wirecloud with Docker.
Is there any template already cooked for that ?

Otherwise I was considering to go a path similar to this tutorial
https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there are no docker templates for deploying WireCloud. The link you have posted looks good as starting point.

I suggest you to open a ticket in the [WireCloud's issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) or to make a pull request if you are going to create a docket template and don't mind to share it. You can get support for creating such a template from the WireCloud team in the issue tracker.

**Update:** WireCloud is now available on [docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wirecloud/fiware-wirecloud/).

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated ;)

Comment: I also find out there was something going on in this subject two months go https://github.com/crismaproject/crisma-wirecloud

Comment: great to know, they also have a repository on [docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/peterkutschera/crisma-wirecloud/), although they have not uploaded the image.